# Push notification works only with foreign third party push provider service?

Tags: android, firebase, ionic-framework, push-notification, ionic3

I'm building an App with Ionic 3 and using Firebase as push provider with Android build. The Image below shows the schema which now is working (not GCM but Firebase)

[image]

By the way I would like to know if it's possible (and how to) **to build the push provider by myself** and where could i find some information, I searched all google but i did'nt found any kind of response. Push notification **ONLY WORKS** with a push provider foreign from my company (Firebase, OneSignal.. etc)?

EDIT: **My purpose is to not use any kind of third party service like firebase or APNS or OneSignal etc, i would like to build it by myself**

Sorry but the Mobile it's not my IT background.
:)

Answer (score 2):

You can send push notifications using your own server via `Firebase`.
Follow these steps.

- Go to Firebase Console and Create a Project.
- Go to **CLOUD MESSAGING** in **Project Settings**.
- You will see `Server key`,`Legacy server key`, `Sender ID` in Project credentials.
- Only thing you need is `Server key`. Copy the `Server key`.
- You need to send `post` request to 'https://fcm.googleapis.com/fcm/send'.

**Headers for Post Request**

You need to set two headers.

1. Content-Type : 'application/json'
2. Authorization : 'key=Server key'

Replace `Server key` with what you copied from firebase cloud messaging in project settings.

**Payloads**

You will have to change your payload according to ionic push plugin.(cordova-plugin-fcm,cordova-plugin-firebase).

```
{
   "to" : 'Push Device Token',
   "notification" : {
        "title": 'Title for Push Message',
         "body" : 'Push Message'
    }
}
```

---

```
{
   "to" : 'Push Device Token',
   "content_available": boolean,
   "priority": "high",
   "data": {
       "show_in_foreground": boolean,
       "body": 'Push Message'
     }
}
```

**Code Sample**

If you are using `NodeJS`, You can send post request using `request npm module`.

```
var request = require('request');
var PUSH_API_URL = 'https://fcm.googleapis.com/fcm/send';
var  AUTHORIZATION = 'key=XXXXXXXXX'; //Replace XXXXXXXXX with your Server key
var payload = {
   "to" : 'Push Device Token',
   "notification" : {
        "title": 'Title for Push Message',
         "body" : 'Push Message'
    }
};

request.post(
    PUSH_API_URL,
{
  json: payload,
  headers:{
    'Authorization' : AUTHORIZATION,
    'Content-Type' : 'application/json'
  }} , function(error, response, body){
  if (error) {
    // TODO: handle the error
  }
  else if(response.statusCode === 200){
    // TODO: handle the success response
  }
  else{

  }
});
```

Hope this will help you. If you need to clarify anything comment below. Read more from [Firebase Documentation](https://firebase.google.com/docs/).

Comment: No, thanks but i already have the service you described as you can see from the image. I edited my question in a more clear form, **I would like to know if it's possible to NOT use in ANY KIND OF WAY third party services** like Firebase, OneSignal, APNS etc..